# Underscan issue with iPhone 5 Lightning HDMI adapter

Tags: ios

I am trying to mirror what's on my iPhone to an external display but I can't remove the underscan. All my searches for an answer lead back to "overscanCompensation". Since this is a property of UIScreen, I'm not sure where to add it if I'm not explicitly creating a new UIScreen as mirroring is now automatic.

Auto-mirroring through Lightning HDMI adapter screenshot:
http://blog.axelgimenez.net/dp7-capture-underscan-issue-1.jpg

The other option is to create a UIScreen when a new display is detected. Please see the code below and note that I did use "overscanCompensation = 3". Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I've tried all the other overscanCompensation options with no luck.

```
- (void)checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent
{
    if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
    {
        // Get the screen object that represents the external display.
        UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
        secondScreen.overscanCompensation = 3;

        // Get the screen's bounds so that you can create a window of the correct size.
        UIScreenMode *screenMode = [[secondScreen availableModes] lastObject];
        CGRect screenBounds = (CGRect){.size = screenMode.size};

        self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

        // Set up initial content to display...
        self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        // Show the window.
        self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the display that the code above creates:
http://blog.axelgimenez.net/dp7-capture-underscan-issue-2.jpg

Same issue of underscan. Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI - Using the Lightning to HDMI adapter, I connected my iPhone 5 to a SmallHD dp7 monitor. The monitor lets me take screen captures. The underscan also appears when I plug into my TV.